# Escape URL with perl but reserved character is not working

Tags: perl, escaping

I was trying to use bash, but it seems some package installation is required, so I want to give Perl a try and hope to use a clean and only one command to achieve it.

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use URI::Escape;
my $string = "https://aá-brø.com/sub/index.php";
my $encode = uri_escape($string);
print $encode;
```

Expect output:

```
https://a%C3%A1-br%C3%B8.com/sub/index.php
```

Actual output:

```
https%3A%2F%2Fa%C3%A1-br%C3%B8.com%2Fsub%2Findex.php
```

I checked https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Escape, and it seems those char(:, /, + ..etc) should be reserved or maybe I was missing something.

One command solution, so far one command is working. But welcome to share if there's shortened method.

```
perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_escape($ARGV[0]);' "https://aá-brø.com/sub/index.php"
```

Comment: Note that is you are going to include wide characters in the source, you should `use utf8` so perl interprets them correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To cite from the documentation of [URI::Escape](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Escape):

> The default set of characters to be escaped is all those which are not part of the unreserved character class shown above as well as the reserved characters. I.e. the default is:
>
> ```
> "^A-Za-z0-9\-\._~"
> ```

So it behaves exactly as documented. If you want to treat `:/` as safe you have to explicitly say so, i.e.

```
my $unsafe = "^A-Za-z0-9\-\._~:/";  
my $encode = uri_escape($string, $unsafe);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So I tried perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_escape("https://aá-brø.com/sub/index.php", "^A-Za-z0-9\-\._~:/")' based on your advice and it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only trying to escape the host, do you want punycode here instead? Major browsers support that as a way to encode hosts (and only hosts) with wide characters as ASCII. And, the major URI-handling modules in Perl already support it:

```
use utf8;
use v5.10;

use Mojo::URL;

my $url = Mojo::URL->new( "https://aá-brø.com/sub/index.php" );
say $url;
```

The output is something like this:

```
https://xn--a-br-5na5l.com/sub/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing ["URL encoding"](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_urlencode.asp) with ["hostname encoding" (IDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name))!

`uri_escape` wouldn't change the hostname, and if it did, it wouldn't work (as URI).